# Trouble with populating JTable and JTextFields

Tags: java, user-interface, nullpointerexception, awt

I have various classes representing various types of program-genres (comedy, drama etc).

I have a text file filled with '-' seperated values that get read by a class called Processing and puts them into a LinkedList.

I have another class GUI_g that creates the GUI. It has 2 JTables. One for the list and 1 for the Channel. The JTable listTable gets filled from the linkedlist and whenever a user clicks on a row, the textfields' text changes accordingly.

I tried with 5 fields (Title, Genre and Duration, Actor, Director) and it worked, with the 3 textfields showing different text according to what row is clicked. However when I added all the needed values, an error comes up and no fields are filled.

I have two problems:

If it's a MusicVideo the cells are not filled up (as it should be) however it returns an error when copying data to the JTextFields
The Snyopsis column remains empty and is not filled.
Below are the classes (the ones mainly used). If you need others tell me and I'll upload.

GUI_g: http://pastebin.com/KsZBwgtR
ProgramTableModel: http://pastebin.com/6Rc2bVxa
Processing: http://pastebin.com/8f8iteVK
Program: http://pastebin.com/NU3XGvM8

This is the error I get:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at GUI_g$1.mouseClicked(GUI_g.java:205)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6507)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6269)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4501)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Image example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is line 205 in your GUI_g class (as the compiler stated).

```
String actor = listTable.getValueAt(row, column+3).toString();
```

You didn't check or clean the input value before you tried to use the toString() method.

you can't use a method on a null value, of course.

You need to check all inputs (not just this one). Since you have a lot of fields you should make a helper method/class to do that for you and return a clean input.

If you just want to get around this one quickly, do this:

```
String actor = " ";
T input = listTable.getValueAt(row, column+3);
if (input != null) actor = input.toString();
return actor;
```

Replace 'T' with whatever object you were trying to check.

Comment: Can you kindly explain with what exactly I should replace 'T' with? I did not quite understand

Comment: @Brian : The toString() method is a java.lang.Object method, so it could belong to any object. I didn't bother going through your code to find the method that listTable.getValueAt(...) refers to, but whichever object you are returning from that method - you just need to set T to that type (T stands for type, btw).

Comment: ahh ok thanks. also.. why isn't the synopsis field there for each object?

Comment: I tried doing this code  `if (listTable.getValueAt(row, column+8) == null) { etc }`. but it didnt work

Comment: @Brian I'm sorry I wouldn't be able to know that without sieving through your entire code or compiling it (neither of which I can be bothered to do-no offence). You have a few options; 1) edit your answer and post only relevant code to your problem so someone is more likely to debug it for you or 2) create an SSCCE of your problem (short, compilable example of your program with all code un-related to the problem left out) then post a new question with that.

Comment: Or if you want to start debugging your own code, you can try to follow the path of your program and find out where it takes a wrong turn. For example, if you are relying on the value of some object - make a System.out.println() in several key locations where that value might or should change and print the location of code and its new value. It will help you to understand the logic of your program and find the error.

Comment: @Brian The code you posted is very long, I highly doubt it is all relevant to your problem. You should narrow it down by starting off with only the method that is supposed to set the `synopsis` field, and then if necessary include other methods included in that method (so we know what they do) and then maybe other places where the `synopsis` field is edited by your program. Otherwise, just create an SSCCE (http://sscce.org)